# first portion of If statement is being passed over; optional error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, if-statement

First off, here is a link to my simple little GPA project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/prkf2e3u6ok7jmo/AACY8b8_kDfigxluJyEzdZbGa?dl=0 .

```
import UIKit

class calccontroller: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var GPA1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Credits1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var GPA2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Credits2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.






}








override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func calculatorButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if GPA1 == nil || GPA2 == nil || Credits1 == nil || Credits2 == nil           {
        let title = "Oops"
        let message = "Please add a value to each text field"
        let okText = "OK"

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message,     preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let okayButton = UIAlertAction(title: okText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okayButton)

       presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {



        let gpa1text = Float(GPA1.text!)!
        let gpa2text = Float(GPA2.text!)!
        let credits1text = Float(Credits1.text!)!
        let credits2text = Float(Credits2.text!)!

        let firstGrade = gpa1text * credits1text
        let secondGrade = gpa2text * credits2text
        let allGPA = firstGrade + secondGrade
        let allCredits = credits1text + credits2text
        let finalGrade = allGPA / allCredits

        answerLabel.text = "\(finalGrade)"

        GPA1.resignFirstResponder()
        GPA2.resignFirstResponder()
        Credits1.resignFirstResponder()
        Credits2.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}


}
```

Anyways, I have a simple 4 text field, 1 button, and 1 label set up.  I thought I had my code set up successfully that if each text field was not holding a value, a ui alert value would pop up asking for a value in each text box.  If there are 4 values, then the app would complete the "math."  However, when I leave all 4 empty or if I click the button when all 4 are filled and then delete 1 text field, my app crashes... "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".  I find it frustrating (which could be a simple mistake on my end, but in my mind I shouldn't be having this value this my pop up alert is meant to be used when a text field is nil.

Thank you for your time, Jon.

Comment: Please don't post a picture, post the actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if logic is incorrect.

Since you create `IBOutlet` and check for nil, it will always return false if you instantiate your View Controller from storyboard or nib.

What you want to do is check its value is empty or not. So something like this should do the trick

```
if GPA1.text.isEmpty || GPA2.text.isEmpty || Credits1.text.isEmpty || Credits2.text.isEmpty {
    // show alert
} else {
    // do your calculation
}
```

Comment: It was my mistake to overpass the variable text.  However, with your logic (unless I am misunderstanding), I should have      if GPA1.text == nil || GPA2.text == nil || Credits1.text == nil || Credits2.text == nil {.  Unfortunately, I am still having the previous error(s) occur.

Comment: Don't check for nil, check for empty string instead. You could use my above code or use `if GPA1.text == "" || GPA2.text == "" || Credits1.text == "" || Credits2.text == ""`

Comment: Ah! I'm sorry, I was unaware of the "isEmpty" status.  However, it worked!  Thank you, seto nugroho!